# gcc error - typedef is initialized (use decltype instead)

Tags: c, gcc

I'm compiling some C code, and I get the error

```
typedef 'A' is initialized (use decltype instead)
```

On one of my struct declarations.  What could be causing this?

Comment: Perhaps it's caused by the line of code GCC echoed along with the error, and you neglected to cut-n-paste into the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am able to reproduce that with the simple program

```
typedef int A = 3;
```

`typedef` declares an alias to a type; it does not declare a variable. So if you want an instance of `struct my_struct` named `A`, you cannot also have `typedef struct my_struct { ... } my_struct` in the same declaration.

Comment: @Matthew: `decltype` is the C++0x name for `__typeof__`. It might depend on flags or version.